# How to know if the current path is a secure path or not, in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Consider that a request is sent to this path:

```
http://domain/users/1534
```

This URL is in public security, so everyone can see it without being authenticated in the site (without being logged in).

Now consider that another URL should be secure:

```
http://domain/admin/update-user
```

This URL should pass the authentication process.

Now, In my code, somewhere I need to know if the current path is a secure path or not (please don't ask why, and also by secure path I don't mean SSL, I'm just talking about paths for which login is required).

How can I know that `HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` is a secure path?

**Update:** What I need is something like:

```
SecurityHelper.ShouldCurrentRequestPathBeAuthenticated(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you implement the authorization process. Somewhere you will need to define it, so that's how you know if it's secure path.

Standard ASP.NET would use the location/security settings in this case.

If your using standard `authentication/authorization` then I believe you can use [CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.urlauthorizationmodule.checkurlaccessforprincipal.aspx).

```
UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(virtualPath, user, verb);
```

Comment: I need a method. What do mean by `location/security`? See the update.

Comment: A method based on if you are using standard authorization or do you have your own logic for this?

Comment: Standard authorization (`FormsAuthentication` class).