# How to check a requested path (URL) has authentication rules in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, security, httprequest, httpmodule

I have a folder hierarchy in my ASP.NET solution, like this:

[image]

Everything in `Reseller` folder should be authenticated, and is considered a secure resource. But anything in `Services` folder is just public, and there is no need to authenticate any request coming for the web service `ProductServices.asmx`.

Now, I want to hook into the `AuthenticateRequest` of the request process pipeline and there, before user is authenticated, I want to see if the request is for a public, or a secure path. I know that I can use `UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` and I actually have asked that in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316584/how-to-know-if-the-current-path-is-a-secure-path-or-not-in-asp-net). But `UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` is a method which can be used, just after the request is authenticated. However, before any authentication, I want to know if the requested path is secure or not. In other words, is there any `authentication` element defined for the requested path anywhere in it's folder hierarchy in any web.config file, or not.

A pseudo-code of what I want could be something like:

```
UrlAuthorizationModule.IsRequestedPathSecure(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` method (as you mentioned) but using a `GenericPrincipal` representing an anonymous user like so:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity(string.Empty, string.Empty);
    IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] { });

    bool hasAccess = UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(Request.Path, principal, "GET");

    if(!hasAccess)
    {
        //Anonymous access not permitted to the current URL.
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried your code, but the `secure` is `true`. I also added `<allow users="?"/>` or `<allow users="*"/>` to the `Services` folder web.config, but no success. The path is `/Services/ProductServices.asmx/GetWizardContainer`. I'm calling this method from jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not very clear. The code above will return true if the anonymous user has access and false if not. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you can forbid/grant access to your hidden resources by using *location* element of web.config see [HOW TO: Control Authorization Permissions in an ASP.NET Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871) for description. It gives you possibility of granting access on folder or aspx/asmx basis. IIS will return 403 HTTP error code for forbidden locations and not process requests to those if users don't have permissions

Comment: yeah, I know that. Thanks for your answer. What I want to do, is to know if the requested path belongs to one of the secured resources, and I want to do this in code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **web.config** file to Reseller and Write following Code into it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow roles="ResellerUser,ResellerAdmin" />
          <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and also add a web.config file to **Service** folder and write follwoing code into it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <pages theme="">
        </pages>
 <authorization>
  <allow roles="ResellerUser, ResellerAdmin" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Note to **Page theme=""** it is necessary.